# How to prevent a System.IndexOutOfRangeException in a LINQ WHERE?

Tags: c#, linq, split

I'm facing this exception when I'm using `String.Split` with random strings.

```
List<string> linhas = new List<string>();

linhas.Add("123;abc");
linhas.Add("456;def");
linhas.Add("789;ghi");
linhas.Add("chocolate");

var novas = linhas.Where(l => l.ToString().Split(';')[1]=="def");
```

Comment: Note you don't need the `ToString` in there.

Comment: You get the exception because of last itme in list which doesn't contain a `;` (`linhas.Add("chocolate");`)

Comment: This question has nothing to do with LINQ. What did you already do to investigate this issue? To get you started: Execute `"chocolate".Split(';')[1]`.

Comment: @usr: I am with you. It's not a special LINQ problem but a common exception if you try to access a collection at a non-existing index. But it's somehow related to LINQ anyway. If you aren't familiar with LINQ it seems to be limited. For example, you can't use an `if..else` and if you don't know anonymous types you don't know how to store intermediate results.

Comment: @TimSchmelter that's actually a good point. It's harder to mitigate in this context.

Comment: this code is just a example, in actual world i will don't know wich values come from the list...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The last string `"chocolate"`doesn't contain a `";"`, so `String.Split` returns an array with a single string `"chocolate"`. That's why you get the exception if you try to accesss the second.

You could use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb494386(v=vs.100).aspx) which returns `null` for strings instead:

```
var novas = linhas.Where(l => l.Split(';').ElementAtOrDefault(1) == "def");
```

A longer approach using an anonymous type:

```
var novas = linhas
    .Select(l => new { Line = l, Split = l.Split(';') })
    .Where(x => x.Split.Length >= 2 && x.Split[1] == "def")
    .Select(x => x.Line);
```

Comment: while this would "work" (for some given definition of work) I think a lot would be won from sitting down for a minute, thinking about why there are items in the list that don't have what we need. is it a problem with the list? should it be a bunch of tuples/KVpairs? should we sanitize the input? etc. I think this is a case where merely "getting it to work" is hacky and will only lead to similar problems later on. identify the business requirement and find a better way to encapsulate it.

Comment: @kai: i have absolutely no idea for what OP needs it. So i can't make assumptions about whether this is a good approach or not. We know too little and OP's sample might also be simpified.

Comment: You don't have to assume to believe that the op is not exactly the most experienced developer and probably has an x/y problem here :/

Comment: @Will: all i can see is that he tries to split by `;` . That's not an x-y problem but a bad way to parse csv. If at all i could recommend him to use a real csv parser instead of `String.Split`. If a "column"-value could contain a semicolon he definitely needs to use one. Maybe he should also use a class with several properties instead. But again, i don't know the background.

Comment: I agree that it's unfeasible to give a more detailed concrete solution to OP given the information provided, I just think it's worth mentioning that if you're asking this question, you probably have larger issues, and it's probably pretty important to become aware of this, since it'll only get more expensive to change as time goes by,

Comment: @Will Just because someone *may* be inexperienced (or maybe they just don't know `C#`), doesn't mean we should jump to the conclusion that it's an x/y problem. For all we know, they *only care* about rows which match the format. It's not out of the realm of possibility at all.

Comment: @Rob Okay guys, I don't feel that strongly about it. No need to blow up the comments thread over it. I can speak from my personal experience, that whenever I found myself in a rabbit hole like this my *real* problem was that I could accomplish my goals using a different, simpler, robust pattern that I just didn't know about at the time.  But maybe I'm an uncommon star in the cosmos, I dunno.  Good day to you all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to expand a little on Tim's answer and show a way to do a few extra things within your LINQ queries.

You can expand the logic within you `Where` clause to do some additional processes, which can make your code a bit more readable. This would be good for something small:

```
var novas = linhas.Where(l => 
            {
                var parts = l.Split(':');

                return parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] == "def" : false;
            });
```

If you need multiple statements, you can wrap the body of your clause within curly braces, but then you need the `return` keyword.

Alternatively, if you have a lot of information that would make something inline like that unreadable, you can also use a separate method within your query.

```
public void FindTheStringImLookingFor()
{
    var linhas = new List<string>();

    linhas.Add("123;abc");
    linhas.Add("456;def");
    linhas.Add("789;ghi");
    linhas.Add("chocolate");

    var words = linhas.Where(GetTheStringIWant);
}

private bool GetTheStringIWant(string s)
{
    var parts = s.Split(':');

    // Do a lot of other operations that take a few lines.

    return parts.Length > 1 ? parts[1] == "def" : false;
}
```